# EndlessAdapter only loads one page

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm using the absurdly simple EndlessAdapter to load paged data from Facebook. In my project the `EndlessAdapter` to wrap a custom `BaseAdapter`. I'm also using a `PullToRefreshListView` which is from this [library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). Everything loads fine to start up, I get the data for the next page load, I scroll to the bottom of the list, the next page of data loads and populates, but when I scroll to the bottom again, nothing happens. I have log checks for the methods and `chacheInBackground()` doesn't run at all after the first successful page load.

I thought it might have to do with the "pull to refresh" library and the adapter not being able to detect the ListView position or something, so I got rid of the "pull to refresh" and still had the same issue.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_feed, container, false);
    if(appState.getNewsFeed()==null){
        refreshListener.onRefresh(refreshFeedList);
        Log.i("NewsFeed", "executing Request");
        if(appState.lastFeed().contains("lastFeed") && feedAdapter == null){
            try {
                String lastFeedString = appState.lastFeed().getString("lastFeed", "null");
                JSONObject lastFeedObject = new JSONObject(lastFeedString);
                JSONArray lastFeedArray;
                lastFeedArray = lastFeedObject.getJSONArray("data");
                appState.setNewsFeed(lastFeedArray);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            updateFeed();
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.i("NewsFeed", "recreating adapters from existing data");
        updateFeed();
    }

    return view;
}

public void updateFeed(){
    refreshFeedList = (PullToRefreshListView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedList);
    feedList = refreshFeedList.getRefreshableView();
    feedList.setDividerHeight(0);
    feedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), appState.getNewsFeed());
    endlessAdapter = new EndlessFeed(feedAdapter);
    refreshFeedList.setAdapter(endlessAdapter);
    refreshFeedList.setOnRefreshListener(refreshListener);
    refreshFeedList.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
}

public class EndlessFeed extends EndlessAdapter {

    @Override
    protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("NewsFeed", "running getPendingView()");
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.loading_view, null);
        return (row);
    }

    public EndlessFeed(BaseAdapter wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean cacheInBackground() throws Exception {
        Log.i("NewsFeed", "running cacheInBackground()");
        nextPageRequest.setCallback(nextPageCallback);
        nextPageRequest.executeAndWait();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void appendCachedData() {
        try {
            appState.addToNewsFeed(requestResponse);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//          onDataReady();
    }
}
```

The JSONArray sent into the adapter is saved as a global variable with getter and setter methods in an `Application` subclass.

Since I recreate the adapters and call `setAdapter()` in the `onCreateView()` method, if I change to a different fragment (via one of the clickable things in the `ListView`) and then navigate back to this fragment, it'll load another page of data. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is clearly in Commonsware's [documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) on how the `EndlessAdapter` is intented to work:

> Your `EndlessAdapter` subclass also needs to implement
>   `cacheInBackground()`. (...) This method returns a boolean, **which
>   needs to be true if there is more data yet to be fetched**, false
>   otherwise.

Since you're always returning `false` from `cacheInBackground()`, it will never get run again after the first time. Hence it only loads more data once when you scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Ahhh thanks. I took that statement to mean that you have to return `false` if that given page is done loading, not if the entire thing never has to load more data again.